# unconfigured columnfamily error during insert

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

> I have the following user info object mapped to a table "user_info" in my keyspace "data_collection". I have created the "user_info" table in my cassandra database. I am using spring data cassandra for connecting to cassandra database from JAVA and the spring annotations as below.

```
@Table(name="user_info",keyspace="data_collection", caseSensitiveKeyspace = false,caseSensitiveTable = false)

public class UserInfo {
    @PartitionKey
    private UUID id;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn
    private String email;

    private int phone;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public int getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(int phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

> I am using the following code to insert a record into my "user_info" table.

```
    @Autowired
    CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate;

    public void saveUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo){
        logger.debug("userInfo "+new Gson().toJson(userInfo));
        String email = userInfo.getEmail();
        Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from("user_info");
        select.where(QueryBuilder.eq("email", email));
        logger.debug("Query "+select.toString());
        UserInfo existingUser = cassandraTemplate.selectOne(select, UserInfo.class);
       if(existingUser!=null){
            cassandraTemplate.update(userInfo);
       }
       else{
            cassandraTemplate.insert(userInfo);
       }

    }
```

> My selectOne is working properly whereas during insert I am getting the following exception. I have clearly mapped the UserInfo.java class to the table name "user_info" using annotation above. I don't know why the insert is trying to happen to the table "userinfo".

```
org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraInvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily userinfo; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily userinfo
    at org.springframework.cassandra.support.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:128)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(CqlTemplate.java:946)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:930)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:278)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:559)
    at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:1333)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doUpdate(CassandraTemplate.java:895)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.update(CassandraTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.update(CassandraTemplate.java:532)
```

> Please find below the description of the table in cassandra.

```
CREATE TABLE user_info (
  name text,
  email text,
  phone int
  PRIMARY KEY ((email))
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Quick update : I just tried saving another class Test.java. It was mapped to a table "test_info". I got the following error

```
org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraInvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily test; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily test
at org.springframework.cassandra.support.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:128)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(CqlTemplate.java:946)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:930)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlTemplate.java:912)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:278)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.doExecute(CqlTemplate.java:559)
at org.springframework.cassandra.core.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:1323)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:708)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:290)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:285)
```

I am just wondering if my Java class name and the table name in cassandra should always be the same. Because its looking for the columnfamily "test" instead of "test_info" which I have specified in the @Table annotation.

> Below is the description of my keyspace

```
CREATE KEYSPACE data_collection WITH replication = {
  'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
  'replication_factor': '3'
};
```

**EDIT - SOLVED :** 
I found the solution based on the conversation with @pinkpanther. 
I had imported com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table instead of org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table which is why it didn't honor the table name mapping. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try your query with cqlsh and check if the table exist, also make sure you connected to the right contact point and keyspace

Comment: Spring Data for Apache Cassandra is no ORM...there are inherently no relations in Cassandra so it's just an object mapper.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam My query in cqlsh works fine. And even through Java my fetch is working as expected without any error. I am not sure if its because of the select object where I specify the table name explicitly, but it works. I have problem only during insert. And yes I am connected to the correct keyspace.

Comment: @mp911de I have edited my question. I use Spring Data for connecting to Cassandra database from my application.

Comment: @lazytc I'm suspecting you have used a wrong strategy class while creating keyspace which strategy did you use? Could you give describe output of your keyspace?

Comment: @pinkpanther I have edited the question and added my table description. I am new to cassandra. Let me know if i should provide anymore details. Thanks.

Comment: @lazytc I was asking about the description of keyspace

Comment: @pinkpanther I have added the description of keyspace as well now.

Comment: @lazytc see my answer, also how many nodes you have?

Comment: Seems like it's ignoring the name="user_info"  in Table annotation. From which package are you using @Table ? is it from datastax driver or org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table?

Comment: @pinkpanther com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table this is the package. Is it wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your help @pinkpanther. The problem was with wrong package import. I have added that as an edit to my question.

Comment: @lazytc I've added this as an answer for future visitors, please accept the answer if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be with the package import of Table, Spring Data Cassandra needs `org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table`. Replace the imported `com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table` with it.